# How show two rows in single row by using Table ,td and tr?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

[image]

I have long list due to which i want to show group of tow rows show in single rows.
how can i achieve this? By using table tr and td because i get this data in repeater in asp.net.

Comment: Please provide more context for your question. Are you using any CSS framework? What elements does the list consist of now? Does the solution need to be responsive, or fixed?

Comment: Show us the HTML markup that produces this.

Comment: Question is too open-ended, but here's a simple way of doing it: `<style>
  div:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
  }
</style>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>`